# подогнув под себя ноги — выделяется ли запятыми?

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли выделять конструкцию "подогнув под себя ноги" запятыми как деепричастный оборот? Или оно тесно связано со сказуемым и передает образ действия? Спасибо!

```
Он сидел(,) подогнув под себя ноги(,) и уминал бутерброд.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оборот передаёт образ действия (*сидел с подогнутыми ногами*). Запятые не нужны.

Похожие примеры Розенталя:
*Яков сидел опустив ноги.

Она сидела чуть откинув голову.

Писал он обычно наклонив голову.

Огромного роста, редкой силы, волосатый, он ходил по земле наклоня голову, как бык.*